# atan(x) gives me wrong values?

Tags: c, trigonometry

I got this function in my code:

```
-(void)printAngle
{
    int width = p2_t.x-cp1_t.x;
    int height = p2_t.y-cp1_t.y;
    if (width != 0) {
        CCLOG(@"%i * %i", width, height);
        CCLOG(@"%f", (float)atan(height/width)*(180/M_PI));
    }
}
```

Heres a snippet from the output:

```
2011-12-06 20:46:52.074 x[12392:c503] 24 * 13
2011-12-06 20:46:52.074 x[12392:c503] 0.000000
2011-12-06 20:46:52.108 x[12392:c503] 25 * 15
2011-12-06 20:46:52.108 x[12392:c503] 0.000000
```

That means that arctan(13/24) in degrees is 0. Which is not correct. So why am i getting 0? Is it something with types im doing wrong?

It gets some angles correct:

```
2011-12-06 20:51:11.956 x[12436:c503] 12 * 129
2011-12-06 20:51:11.957 x[12436:c503] 84.289404
2011-12-06 20:51:11.989 x[12436:c503] 10 * 132
2011-12-06 20:51:11.990 x[12436:c503] 85.601292
```

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with Obj-C. Your issue is really just a pure C problem wrapped up in an ObjC method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using integer math and expecting a floating point result. This won't work. Change `width` and `height` to be `float` instead and you should get the expected results.

In case you are unaware, in C, doing division with integers produces an integral result. So evaluating `13/24` is producing `0` instead of `0.541666667`. By either casting one of the variables to `(float)` before performing the division, or just using `float` to begin with, you'll get the floating-point number you expect.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Also, when all you expect is a float (instead of a double), why not using atanf()?